# Connecting to another server through squid

Tags: proxy, squid, tunneling

I have 2 servers A and B, I don't have access to B normally, but I can access B through server A. I want my http requests to be proxied through server B.
If I set up squid on server B, I can't access it. So I want to set up squid on server A and somehow make server A proxy my requests to server B.

Hope this is not confusing! How can I achieve this?

P.S. I have set up my squid on Port 3128.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need exactly is a squid proxy chain.
For this purpose you need to install squid on both machines, but configure server A to send any requests it receives to server B.

Here's an article about it:
https://www.rootusers.com/configure-squid-proxy-to-forward-to-a-parent-proxy/

Comment: I read that article but couldn't figure out what to do exactly to get the desired results. Could you elaborate more on this?